# why does D.get(k,v) seem to always execute v if v is returned from a function?

Tags: python

```
D = {'a':1}
D.get('a', print('hah'))
```

Although 1 is successfully returned, I also get 'hah'. Why? it seems as if python needs to evaluate what it is that is supposed to return if 'a' doesn't exist, and is somehow tricked because it expected just a variable.

Also, is there a smart way to get the intended behaviour (no execution of the print function), other than this:

```
D.get('a', print('hah') if not D.get('a') else None)
```

Mind you, the print() here is a MWE. I really need to use a function that returns a list.

Comment: D has become a set, not a dict anymore. The method `.get()` won't work.

Comment: you're abusing `get`.

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake, it's a dict, and the print is just for illustrating, i really need a function there.

Comment: A general comment: MWEs are not always the way to go. I was trying to keep it simple so that I don't overburden you guys with details, but in the end I realized I should have gone with the full example (which contains a get within a setdefault !! and a function returning a list, which needs to be inserted into the dict as a value ). Or, the MWEs have to be crafted much more carefully than I originally thought.

Comment: No idea what MWE is.  Google says it is a corporation, or its stock symbol.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy "Minimal Working Example", I imagine.

Comment: What SO calls MCVE, minimal complete verifiable example, which actually is the way to go, including here.

Comment: hehe, yeap, sorry, i copied MWE over from tex.stackexchange.com :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When python calls a function, all arguments are first evaluated, because python doesn't know, whether one parameter is needed or not.

If you don't want the evaluation, you have to work with `if` or exceptions:

```
D = {'a': 1}
try:
    a = D['a']
except KeyError:
    a = print('hah')
```

With two lookups, so less elegant:

```
a = D['a'] if 'a' in D else print('hah')
```

Or if you can guarantee, that the values in your dictionary never evaluate to `False` (no empty string, empty tuple, 0, 0.0, ..., **be cautious!**):

```
a = D.get('a') or print('hah')
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, python *evaluates the arguments first*, and then calls the function.

Print the result of `get`:

```
print(D.get('a', 'hah'))
```

Or, if you want to check for existence:

```
if "a" in D:
    print('there')
```

Answer (score 2):

Python isn't lazy evaluated. So your

```
D.get('a', <function call that returns None>)
```

starts by evaluating the functions that are fed to `get` and then does the lookup. If `'a'` wasn't in the dictionary, you'd still get the printed statement, but the `get` call would return `None`.

You can contrive something like lazy evaluation out of python by using functions instead of values, of course:

```
d = {'a': lambda x: 1}
d.get('a', lambda x: print('hah'))('dummy function argument')
```

but the awkwardness of this should be pretty self-evident. I think everyone would agree that this is "unpythonic". The arguably nicer way would be:

```
def return1():
    return 1

def print_hah():
    print('hah')

d = {'a': return1}
d.get('a', print_hah)()
```

But again, this isn't very pretty. The main issue is that python wasn't really designed to be a functional language; you can do it, it's just not going to look nice.

Comment: i was really hoping there'd be a better way, i'm bemused... in the end, i wrote it in 4 freakin' lines :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `print` part:

```
D = {'a': 1}
print(D.get('a', 'hah'))
```